# Flyway Over SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, flyway

I'm trying to connect Flyway to an AWS EC2 MySQL instance using TCP over SSH.

Can anyone help with this JDBC URL:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql:/0.0.0.00:3306/database
```

The connection error is;

> Could not connect to address=(host=0.0.0.0)(port=3306)(type=master) :
>   Connection timed out: connect

Comment: If using a local tunnel to remote host, your connection string might need the local loopback address 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the local loopback IP address which is now the virtual location of your database because of the SSH tunnel you're using.

Your connection string would be;

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql:/127.0.0.1:3306/database
```

Comment: Yes but How I set up the bridge ? Putty ?

Comment: @josecarvalho You don't even have the tunnel setup? This has nothing to do with Flyway then, this is a general SSH port forwarding question. Checkout the [`ssh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) man page. You want something like `ssh -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 ec2-instance.com` where `13306` is the local port on your machine and `3306` is the port receiving traffic on the remote end. See this [explain shell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-L+13306%3A127.0.0.1%3A3306+ec2-instance.com) example.

Comment: Following @josecarvalho's example would result in a connection string using port 13306 i.e. flyway.url=jdbc:mysql:/127.0.0.1:13306/database

Comment: Thanks for your answers.